# php regex lookahead - exclude character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I’m trying to extract three parts with a regular expression.
It works for the controller and the id but not for the slug, I can not remove the last -

```
    <?php
    $url = "/cockpit/posts/my-second-article-2-155";
    $routes = [];
    $patterns = "/(?<controller>[a-z]+)\/(?<slug>[a-z0-9\-]+)(?<=\-)(?<id>[0-9]+)/i";
    
    preg_match($patterns, $url, $matches);
    foreach ($matches as $key => $value){
        if(!is_numeric($key)){
            $routes[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    
    var_dump($routes);
```

I get the following result :

```
array(3) {
  ["controller"]=>
  string(5) "posts"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(20) "my-second-article-2-"
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "155"
}
```

But i want this slug :

```
["slug"]=>
  string(20) "my-second-article-2"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```
/(?<controller>[a-z]+)\/(?<slug>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+)-(?<id>[0-9]+)/i
```

Your updated PHP script:

```php
$url = "/cockpit/posts/my-second-article-2-155";
$routes = [];
$patterns = "/(?<controller>[a-z]+)\/(?<slug>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+)-(?<id>[0-9]+)/i";

preg_match($patterns, $url, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_numeric($key)) {
        $routes[$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($routes);
```

This prints:

```
array(3) {
  ["controller"]=>
  string(5) "posts"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(19) "my-second-article-2"
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "155"
}
```

The final portion of the updated regex says to match:

- `[a-z0-9]+` alphanumeric term
- `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+` followed by hyphen and another alphanumeric term, both 1 or more times
- `-` match a literal hyphen
- `[0-9]+` match the id